# ¿salto de personaje en javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

hola buenas tardes estoy diseñando un videojuego para mi clase de paradigmas y estaba diseñando el escenario y los eventos y ya mi programa es capaz de capturar las teclas de arriba derecha y izquierda y abajo, y les programe eventos para por ejemplo con la tecla derecha que se mueva hacia la derecha x++ y izquierda y-- mi pregunta seria como puedo hacer que cuando se presione la tecla de espacio mi personaje pueda saltar.

Este es mi objeto jugador y hay controlo los eventos del jugador donde falta implementar el salto.
package clases;

```
import implementación.juego;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;


public class Jugador extends ObjetoJuego{
//definiendo atributos  
    private int vidas;
    
    //metodo constructor
    
    

    public Jugador(int x, int y, String nombreImagen, int velocidad, int vidas) {
        super(x, y, nombreImagen, velocidad);
        this.vidas = vidas;
    }

    
    

    

    

    

    public int getVidas() {
        return vidas;
    }

    public void setVidas(int vidas) {
        this.vidas = vidas;
    }

    

    //metodo para pintar
    @Override
    public void pintar(GraphicsContext graficos) {
        graficos.drawImage (juego.imagenes.get(nombreImagen),x,y);
    }
    //Se ejecuta por cada iteracion del ciclo de juego.
    @Override
    public void mover() {
        if(x>700)
            x = -80;
            
        if(juego.derecha) 
            //Mover hacia la derecha
            x+= velocidad;
        if(juego.izquierda) 
            //Mover hacia la izquierda
            x-= velocidad;
        if(juego.arriba) 
            //Mover hacia la arriba
            y-= velocidad;
        if(juego.abajo) 
            //Mover hacia la abajo
            y+= velocidad;
    }
}
```

y este es mi objeto juego en donde le estoy diciendo que hacer cuando se presione la tecla space pero quiero que salte.

```
public void gestionEventos() {
      //Registrando el evento cuando se presiona una tecla
    // escena.setOnKeyPressed(new Evento());  
    escena.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        
        //El metodo handle se ejecuta cada vez que presiono una tecla
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent evento) {
                
            switch(evento.getCode().toString()) {
                case "RIGHT":
                    derecha = true;
                    break;
                case "LEFT":
                    izquierda = true;
                    break;
                case "UP":
                    arriba = true;
                    break;
                case "DOWN":
                    abajo = true;
                    break;
                case "SPACE":
                    jugador.setVelocidad(10);
                    break;
                    
            }
        }
        
    });
    
    escena.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
     
        
        //Se ejecuta cuando se suelta una tecla
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent evento) {
            switch(evento.getCode().toString()) {
            case "RIGHT":
                derecha = false;
                break;
            case "LEFT":
                izquierda = false;
                break;
            case "UP":
                arriba = false;
                break;
            case "DOWN":
                abajo = false;
                break;
            case "SPACE":
                jugador.setVelocidad(5);
                
            }
        }
        
    });
  }
```

por favor agradeceria su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Es un tema interesante pero recuerda que la variacion de la posX y posY varia por cada iteracion asi que debes utilizar un FOR para emula esa secuencia de cambio emulando el salto y colocar el limite para que no suba indefinidamente ademas de crear como una especie de arco para que el salto sea hacia adelante o atras. asi que debes tener dos tipos de saltos. y cuando se ejecute....en ese instante no deberias poder mover el personaje....utiliza Threads o Executors.para independizar los movimientos.....porque debes variar ambas coordenadas.
Como he desarrollado juegos tanto en GODOT3D y UNITY....te sugiero que revises como se haria alli ya que es mas comun.